# FX5200 performance boost on noveau drivers?

Tags: drivers, performance, puppylinux

Title. Been using tharpup 6.0.5 32 bit (PAE) on an usb since the hard disk died. Most of my games run badly on the nouveau drivers. Any tips to improve performance?

Comment: fyi:  Unless you got a USB 3.0 port with a high speed usb device, this by itself could be limiting performance.  Games load textures, and stuff in the background and the speed of the storage media can limit performance.

Comment: True, But We're Also talking about the nvidia geforce FX 5200. OpenGL perfromance is low with the propietary drivers, the noveau drivers (which is what i'm currently stuck with since all attempts at installing the propietary nvidia drivers makes the system unbootable, forcing me to delete the personal file.) are quite worse, i'm just wondering if there's any way to push the card/drivers a lil bit to run games better, that's all!

Comment: this is such a low end card from 2003. Buy a new card

Comment: i would say "no dip sherlock", but for this old pentium 4 FX 5200 machine i go way back.